# Fade on JS Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have an existing toggle that is working how I want, but I would like it to fade subtly in and out on transition. How can I add to my existing code to do that? Here is my current code:

```js
    $('#toggle > div').click(function() {
    var producttoggle = $(this).index();
    
    $('#left').toggle(producttoggle === 0 );
    $('#right').toggle(producttoggle === 1 );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">
        <div id="left">left
            <!--  left content block -->
        </div>
        <div id="right">right
            <!--  right content block -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: My recommendation is to use CSS transitions and control it using JS to add/remove the class. A ton of posts about this (and other fade strategies). I'm sure quite a few here on stack overflow as well. Oh and jQuery has baked in fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)** instead of **[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** and rather than pass your test in as an argument (which is incorrect usage of `toggle()`), set it up as an `if/else` statement.

Also (FYI), the JQuery team recommends the use of **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for event binding rather than the older shortcut methods like `.click()`.

```js
$('#toggle > div').on("click", function() {
  // Change the following 1 to a 0 if you want to reverse which element fades
  if($(this).index() === 1){
    $('#left').fadeToggle();
  } else {
    $('#right').fadeToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
div > div {  width:50%; cursor:pointer; }
#left { float:left; background-color:#ff0; }
#right { float:right; background-color:#0ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">
  <div id="left">Click Me</div>
  <div id="right">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'd do is make a keyframe in your CSS code, then you'd make your toggle add an animation style to the element you want. See below:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    10% {opacity: 0.9;}
    20% {opacity: 0.8;}
    30% {opacity: 0.7;}
    40% {opacity: 0.6;}
    50% {opacity: 0.5;}
    60% {opacity: 0.4;}
    70% {opacity: 0.3;}
    80% {opacity: 0.2;}
    90% {opacity: 0.1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Reverse this to make the fadeOut animation. Then, using JS, add this code (sorry, I don't know jQuery):

```
document.getElementById("right").style.animation = "fadeIn 10s 1;";
```

Execute this code using your if statement, and then just make a counter using JS to update the page and execute the animation. Simple!

Comment: For a smooth even animation, just use `from {opacity:0} to {opacity:1}` instead of all those keyframe declarations. But, for this simple of an effect, CSS animations are overkill. A CSS transition would be much simpler. But, the OP said *How can I add to my existing code to do that?* and your solution is completely different than the OP's original code. For this to be a good answer, you should address the question being asked and then add other solutions as you see fit.